# Insert into... select from.... query with where condition

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause, bulkinsert

I want make sql query which will insert values from one table to another table by checking where condition on 1st table.

I have to check is that row present previously in 1st table or not. If not present then add otherwise don't add.

There is query "insert into select from" pattern in sql.

I have tried following query. But it inserts many duplicates.

```
INSERT INTO 
    company_location (company_id, country_id, city_id)
SELECT 
    ci.company_id, hq_location, hq_city
FROM 
    company_info ci, company_location cl 
WHERE  
    ci.company_id <> cl.company_id
    AND cl.country_id <> ci.hq_location
    AND cl.city_id <> ci.hq_city;
```

Duplicate avoiding means that tuple (company_id, country_id, city_id) shouldn't added again. And I have to add from more 4 tables into these table.

Also I require query for removing duplicates from company_location. i.e. combination of (company_id, country_id, city_id) should exist only single time. Keep only one tuple and remove other rows.

Comment: Separate the problem into two: first define a suitable query which returns the values that you want, then use this query to insert values into the second table. It seems that the 'insert into' part of the question is irrelevant.

Comment: @ No'am Newman:There is query "insert into select from" pattern in sql.

Comment: Are there any duplicates in `company_info`? Other than that, I cannot see how this query would insert a record that already exists in `company_location`.

Comment: @vhallac: I have specified that in company_location there will be entries from 4-5 tables. So I have to insert entries into company_location which would be used for search filter. There are not duplicates of combination (company_id,country_id,city_id). And it is inserting duplicates. I have tested it.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I still occasionally get trumped with some operations, such as "anything that doesn't exist in the other table". peufeu gave the right answer using a `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this untested Script helps! It inserts every combination just once.

```
INSERT INTO company_location 
    (company_id,country_id,city_id)
SELECT  distinct ci.company_id, 
        ci.hq_location, 
        ci.hq_city
FROM    company_info ci  
WHERE  ci.company_id NOT IN 
        (SELECT cl1.company_id FROM company_location cl1
            WHERE cl1.country_id = ci.hq_location
            AND cl1.city_id = ci.hq_city
            AND cl1.company_id = ci.company_id)
```

Comment: It is working if company_info have no duplicates. I have to insert also from other tables that having duplicates. So it is not working for it. Thanks for giving time.

Comment: @Sommath Muluk It also should work if there are duplicates in compan_info, because of the distinct. I hope I understood you right.

Comment: I got issue. Your last condition should be cl1.company_id = ci.company_id. That's why it was not considering that tuple. Now it is working fine. Thanks for your support. One more question I require query for removing duplicates from company_location. i.e. combination of (company_id,country_id,city_id) should exist only single time. Keep only one tuple and delete other rows.

Comment: @Sommath Muluk Do you have a row-id in the company_location? That would be needed for a delete statement.

Comment: @cris:primary key is present and name is= "id";

Answer (score 2):

INSERT INGORE works.

- If you want a column (or column set) to be unique, put a UNIQUE constraint on your table. If yu no have UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, therefore, by definition, the table cannot contain any undesirable duplicates, since not putting a UNIQUE constraint means duplicates are desirable.
- Add UNIQUE( company_id,country_id,city_id )(or maybe it's your primary key for that table)
- use INSERT IGNORE

You can also rewrite your query correctly. The query does not do what you think it does, and you cannot do what you want by using the old join syntax from the 18th century.

```
SELECT * FROM t1, t2, t3
```

Is a CROSS JOIN, this means it takes all possible combinations of rows from table t1,t2,t3. Usually the WHERE contains some "t1.id=t2.id" conditions to restrict it and turn it into an INNER JOIN, but "<>" conditions do not do this...

You need a proper LEFT JOIN :

```
INSERT INTO company_location (company_id,country_id,city_id)
SELECT ci.company_id, hq_location, hq_city
FROM company_info ci,
LEFT JOIN  company_location cl ON (
  ci.company_id = cl.company_id
  AND cl.country_id = ci.hq_location
  AND cl.city_id = ci.hq_city
)
WHERE cl.company_id IS NULL
```

Comment: It is working if company_info have no duplicates. I have to insert also from other tables that having duplicates. So it is not working for it. Thanks for giving time.

Answer (score 1):

use `INSERT IGNORE INTO`
from [Mysql Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html)

```
   Specify IGNORE to ignore rows that would cause duplicate-key violations.
```

Comment: also see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842053/mysql-insert-and-select-order-of-precedence

Comment: Link was not helpful. And also it is inserting duplicates. And inserting values though touple is present in table.

Answer (score 1):

Here the answer to your second Question; Query to delete duplicate entries:
Please be careful with the statements they are not tested.

Solution 1:

This solution only works, if you have a row-Id in your table.

```
    DELETE FROM company_location
WHERE id NOT IN
    (SELECT     MAX(cl1.id)
    FROM company_location cl1
        WHERE   cl1.company_id = company_location.company_id
        AND     cl1.country_id = company_location.country_id
        AND     cl1.city_id = company_location.city_id)
```

Solution 2:

This works without row_id. It writes all data into a Temporary table. Deletes the content on the first table. And inserts every tupel just once.
To that solution: Be careful if you have defined constraints on that table!

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_company_location
(
    company_id bigint
    ,country_id bigint
    ,city_id bigint
);

INSERT INTO tmp_company_location
(company_id,country_id,city_id)
SELECT DISTINCT
    company_id
    ,country_id
    ,city_id 
FROM company_location WHERE 1;

DELETE FROM company_location;

INSERT INTO company_location
SELECT DISTINCT
    company_id
    ,country_id
    ,city_id 
FROM tmp_company_location;
```

Comment: @cris: One change was required. Instead of MAX(c1.row_id) MAX(cl1.row_id)
Your solution is working fine. Thanks again.